# React + TypeScript: Type error on resize event

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom-events

Another React + TypeScript event handler question.

How to fix this type error?

```
        const onResize = (
            event: React.UIEvent<Window, "resize">,
        ) => {
            console.log(event.target);
        };

        window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
```

This throws

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "resize", listener: (this: Window, ev: UIEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(event: React.UIEvent<Window, "resize">) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Window, ev: UIEvent) => any'.
      Types of parameters 'event' and 'ev' are incompatible.
        Type 'UIEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'UIEvent<Window, "resize">': nativeEvent, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, persist
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(event: React.UIEvent<Window, "resize">) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
      Type '(event: React.UIEvent<Window, "resize">) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
        Types of parameters 'event' and 'evt' are incompatible.
          Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'UIEvent<Window, "resize">': detail, view, nativeEvent, isDefaultPrevented, and 2 more.  TS2769
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case you can use the "Event" interface.

```
const onResize = (
        event: Event,
    ) => {
        console.log(event.target);
    };
```

> Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'UIEvent<Window, "resize">'

This line is saying that the type `Event` (from `onResize`) is missing some properties that `UIEvent<Window, "resize">` doesn't provide.

**Edit:**
If we want to access properties like `event.target.screen`, you will need to explicitly tell TypeScript the type of your target.

The way to do it is using a generic type to cast it to a proper type:

```
const onResize = (event: Event) => {
  const target = event.target as Window
  console.log(target.screen)
}
```

This will let TypeScript know that the target is of type `window`, that way it will know the `screen` property.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `console.log(event.target.screen);` throws `Property 'screen' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)` . This also happens for other properties on the `event` object. :/

Comment: I see, In that case, I think you will need to explicitly tell TypeScript the type of your target.
The way to do it is using a generic type to cast it to a proper type:

`const onResize = (event: Event) => {const target = event.target as Window; console.log(target.screen)}`

This will let TypeScript know that the element is of type `window` and it will know the `screen` property.
I always try to avoid cast types, but for this case I couldn't find another working solution :/